# React Router 4 use regex failed

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a path like this: `<Route path="/p/:categoryId(/^(?!kategori.*$).*/)" component={DiscoComponent} />` so path beginning with /p/kategori will not go to this path. But it always throw error saying the regex is invalid.

I tried to remove the / so it becomes like this
`<Route path="/p/:categoryId(^(?!kategori.*$).*)" component={DiscoComponent} />` but it also produces error.

Why is it error using valid regex?

Comment: Post your error here.

Comment: Try - `npm install path-to-regexp` - From the docs `Any valid URL path or array of paths that path-to-regexp@^1.7.0 understands.` Refer this https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string